# Prophets & Their Eras

Tags: history, prophets

I wanted to know -- out of historical interest -- approximately how long back some well-known Prophets (Allah's Peace & Blessings on them all) lived.

By approximation (and I may be wrong), I can guess that Prophet Moses (AS) may have lived around 3000-2500 BC, and Prophet Abraham (AS) may have lived around 5000 BC.

I want to know how long back Prophet Noah (AS) came, and also some other Prophets mentioned in the Qur'an? Is there a link to some estimated information about this?

Comment: Historical record before Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) is not very well documented. You will not find very concrete information

Comment: Read or watch "Stories of Prophets (qasas ul anbiya)"  in English or your own language and you will get to know all known & verified things about Prophets. One link is here: http://www.biharanjuman.org/Video-Qasas-ul-Anbiya-English.htm. Google for your own language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a prophets tree with major prophets

[image]

Comment: Source of the dates?

Comment: I don't have source, I received this in a mailing list years ago, but at least it shows the order and give an idea !!

Comment: I tend to distrust unsourced information that gets distributed through email.

Comment: @Anas, the dates seem very suspect; they seem very "compacted." Secondly, since there isn't much in the way of written historical records, we can best arrive at some scholarly estimates (only). Still, +1 for at least a pointer.